# extract value of a numeric array function in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

If I define a function whit two array, for instance like this:

```
from numpy import *
x = arange(-10,10,0.1)
y = x**3
```

How can I extract the value of y(5.05) interpolating the value of the two closer point y(5) and y(5.1)? Now if I want find that value, I use this method:

```
y0 = y[x>5][0]
```

And I should obtain the value of `y` for `x=5.1`, but I think that exist better methods, and probably they are the correct ones.

Comment: `5.05**3` ?  ;) ​​​​​​

Comment: You are right but I would use this in other more complex functions ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [numpy.interp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html), if linear interpolation will suffice:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
>>> y = x**3
>>> np.interp(5.05, x, y)
128.82549999999998
>>> 5.05**3
128.787625
```

And there are a bunch of tools in `scipy` for interpolation [[docs]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html):

```
>>> import scipy.interpolate
>>> f = scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x, y)
>>> f
<scipy.interpolate.fitpack2.LSQUnivariateSpline object at 0xa85708c>
>>> f(5.05)
array(128.78762500000025)
```

Comment: Thank you! It was a trivial question... I didn't know `interp` function

Comment: `UnivariateSpline( x, y, s=0 )` will interpolate exactly, i.e. `f(x) == y`. (Beware: if you smooth with `s > 0`, the `s` value must scale with `y`.)

Answer (score 4):

There's a function for this in numpy/scipy..

```
import numpy as np
np.interp(5.05, x, y)
```